# Extract strings that lie outside the brackets using sed or awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a string of the format abc(something that should be removed) is bad(another thing to remove): basically a string that has some words which are not in parenthesis and some that are in parenthesis. I want to extract the words that are not parenthesized. For eg. in the above example, output should be abc is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed command,

```
sed 's/([^()]*)//g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
abc(something that should be removed) is bad(another thing to remove)
$ sed 's/([^()]*)//g' file
abc is bad
```

Default sed uses BRE (*Basic Regular Expressions*) so you don't need to escape `(` or `)` to match a literal `(`, `)` symbols.